# Machine learning classifying algorithm with "unknown" class

Tags: algorithm

I understand that if I train a ML classifying algorithm on sample pictures of apples, pears and bananas, it will be able to classify new pictures in one of those three categories. But if I provide a picure of a car, it will also classify it in one of those three classes because it has nowhere else to go.

But is there a ML classifying algorithm that would be able to tell if a item/picture is not really beloning to any of the classes it was trained for? I know I could create a "unknown" class and train it on all sorts of pictures that are neither apples, pears or bananas, but the training set would need to be huge I assume. That does not sound very practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT 02/2019:

I agree with the comments below that the following answer in its original form is not correct. You will absolutely need negative samples to provide some balance your training dataset, otherwise your model may not learn useful discriminators between positive and negative samples.

That being said, you do not need to train on every possible negative class, only those which may be present when you are performing inference. This is getting more into how you set the problem up and how you plan to use your trained model.

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Most classification algorithms will output a classification along with a score/certainty measure which indicates how confident that algorithm is that the returned label is correct (based on some internal figuring, this is not an external accuracy evaluation).

If the score is below a certain threshold, you can have it output `unknown` rather than one of the known classes. There is no need to train with negative examples.

Comment: i disagree because false positives can and will happen! to prevent that having a class with random images which don't contain objects of your other classes will most certainly help to prevent false positives. i speak of experience and it is also a common practice. see also recommendation here (they speak of "none_of_the_above" which is their "unknown" class): https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare

Comment: I also disagree, strongly. If you learn a linear classifier between two relatively similar classes (apples and pears), and then show it a car, I would expect that the car is far away from the hyperplane, so the classifier would say "This most definitely is not a pear" and be very sure this is an apple.

Comment: Thank you @andruido and kutschkem , I agree with your criticisms and have updated the answer.

Comment: @kutschkem ^^^^

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this can be found in this paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06233.pdf

The paper also compares the result generated by simply putting the threshold on the final scores and the (OpenMax) technique proposed by the author.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [One-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification). This is the problem of learning membership to a class, as opposed to distinguishing between two classes. This is interesting if there are too few examples of a second class ("not-in-class", let's say), or the "not-in-class" class is not well defined.

Where this popped up for me once was classifying Wikipedia articles for being flawed in some way - since it was not clear that an article not flagged as flawed was really not flawed, one approach was one-class classification. I have to add though that for my problem this did not perform well, so you should compare performance with other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

it certainly helps having a class with random pictures (without objects of your other classes you want to detect) labeled as UNKNOWN class. this will prevent lot's of false positives. this is also best practice. read here to see it used with AutoML: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare